# MSYS2 UCRT64 ld can't find -lpython39

Tags: python, windows, rust, ld, msys2

I am trying to use cargo to build a rust project that uses python. The rustup I installed was targeted for the GNU ABI in MSYS2, and when I try to `cargo build`, and I get an error saying that ld can't find the python library, despite it being installed.

```
= note: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c
= note: C:/msys64/
= note: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-m  = note: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gc
= note: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython3
```

When I run MSYS2 UCRT64, I can run python 3.9, and I can use `which python` to confirm that it is installed in `C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/python`, and when I run `ld -lpython39` (that is, not using cargo or anything) I get that same error

```
$ ld -lpython39
C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lpython39: No such file or directory
```

So, does ld require an -L argument to tell it the location of python39 even though it's in the default location? If so, how do I do so with cargo? Am I not supposed to use rustup and use the rust that comes with MSYS2? The rust website advises against this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by installing `python-devel` and adding to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH by adding to my `~/.bashrc`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib"
```

I figured this out because on a fresh install of Ubuntu, I had the exact same error, and bafflingly, the equivalent directory isn't added to that environment variable by default. So on ubuntu I solved this by adding

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

MSYS2 (at least UCRT64) ships only Python 3.10. The package `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-python` has version `3.10.5-2` and the only library it contains is `/ucrt64/lib/libpython3.10.dll.a`.

Comment: Crap, if that's the case, which MSYS2 environment should I use? I believe cargo is using UCRT64 because I have that on System PATH, so I should be able to change that preference by changing the path I think.

Comment: The normal MinGW/MSVCRT environment of MSYS2 also has Python 3.10 so I think the answer is to update/reconfigure whatever software you have that is expecting you to have Python 3.9.  The software can run `pkg-config --libs python3` to get accurate linker arguments.

Comment: @DavidGrayson What do you mean "the software can run"? Are you saying that I run that in MSYS2 UCRT? Or that I should somehow have Cargo (the software in question) run it?

Comment: First, find whatever file you have that has decided to use `-lpython39`.  It probably isn't hardcoded into Cargo, it's probably part of this mysterious project you are building which you didn't link to.  Then you can think about how to fix it.  Either just update the number there, or make that code more robust by executing my `pkg-config` command above and using the arguments that it returns.  You should also run my `pkg-config` command yourself in the appropriate MSYS2/UCRT bash shell so you can see its output and educate yourself.

Comment: Btw the mysterious project is PyO3. Also when I run pkg-config, I get a blank output, despite having python3 installed. It seems like pkg-config requires a .pc file somewhere and for that file to be on the ```PKG_CONFIG_PATH```